# Should I use randint?

Tags: c++, random, c++17

The `randint` proposal is supposed to provide an intuitive interface for getting random integral numbers. The problem however is that it uses `default_random_engine` and so far has no way of letting you specify the engine it uses. libstdc++ and libc++ both use minstd_rand which is a LCG, which I've read creates poor quality numbers. MSVC uses mt19937 which seems to be the most common on this site.

Is this a big negative of randint?

Comment: It always boils down to your use-case. A well-implemented LCG (number-theory driven parameters) is not that bad and it's really fast. Most applications don't care about the quality of the random numbers that much. If you need more quality, there are a lot of possibilities in the boost library [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), including the high-quality PRNGs of type ranlux [link](http://luscher.web.cern.ch/luscher/ranlux/index.html). Seems Mersenne-twister and ranlux are also part of the STL in modern C++[link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Comment: Lacking those details, I don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: @MSalters Well, you could interpret the question as as "what are all of the factors I should pay attention to when determining if I should use `randint`.  Which is broad.  In any case, OP, can you narrow your problem to a more specific concrete case?